How do I unredact information in the Bestiary?
It seems every bestiary page has a second [Redacted] section that's possible to unlock somehow, since my Skeleton page has a second section but with words instead of [Redacted].
What's the unlock condition for the other section? It's not defeating an Elite, since I've done that for other pages and nothing.
Is it just defeating enough of the enemy? I've killed more than 1000 Skeletons, but not any other enemy...
